# Wubi 12.04 is not using the .ISO file which I've already downloaded

Tags: 12.04, wubi

Wubi is not using the file which is already present in the directory, but previously it got installed 2 times.

My Windows7 is a 64bit, will it have any effect on installing Ubuntu in my system??

Comment: Did you change it's name or something? Is is a special folder in your system, or is it the same as you did install before? Did you check the md5 hash for errors?

Comment: You need to look in the logfile to find out why (look for the last modified file named `wubi-nn.nn-revnnn.log` in the `%TEMP%` directory). Wubi is release sensitive and also validates the ISO. If it's a 12.04 ISO then it will fail if you're online because the latest ISO checksums are for 12.04.1. But running offline with the correct version of Wubi.exe will still work. etc. The log file will indicate the actual reason

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*bcbc answered this (as well as it can be answered, and in a way likely to be helpful to many other Wubi users) in a comment.*</sup>

> You need to look in the logfile to find out why (look for the last
>   modified file named `wubi-nn.nn-revnnn.log` in the `%TEMP%`
>   directory). Wubi is release sensitive and also validates the ISO. If
>   it's a 12.04 ISO then it will fail if you're online because the latest
>   ISO checksums are for 12.04.1. But running offline with the correct
>   version of Wubi.exe will still work. etc. The log file will indicate
>   the actual reason.

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Oct 16 '12 at 17:16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201798/wubi-12-04-is-not-using-the-iso-file-which-ive-already-downloaded#comment251239_201798)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as this WORKED FOR ME:

- Running x64 win7 and mounted a 12.04 LTS x64 Iso
- Get an ISO for your version of Ubuntu which has a wubi.exe inside.
- Mount the ISO or burn the image and insert the CD
- Copy the wubi.exe from the CD to your PC (anywhere. I copied it to D:\OS)
- Disable your internet.
- Run Wubi.exe - should now extract and install from your CD drive / Mounted CD Drive.

Note: The downloaded wubi.exe didnt work, but the one from the CD did, probably pointing out to something version related.